# How to add to value in array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to increase quantity of a product when the id of that product already exists inside an array.

My product array `$arr2` looks like this for example:

```
Array
(
    [productid] => 3
    [productname] => Eikenhout pallet
    [productalias] => eikenhout-pallet
    [productcat] => Eikenhout
    [catalias] => eikenhout
    [quantity] => 1
    [kuubkosten] => 150|1 kuub
)
```

Then I create a session and add all information to it.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
     // and turn session into array
   $_SESSION['producten'] = array();
}

// If id of product does not exist, add it to session
if(!isset($_SESSION['producten'][$arr2['productid']])){
    $_SESSION['producten'][$arr2['productid']] = $arr2;
// Else add to quantity
}else{
    $_SESSION['producten'][$arr2['productid']]['quantity'] += $arr2['quantity'];
}
```

If I then print my session, this is what I get:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [productid] => 3
            [productname] => Eikenhout pallet
            [productalias] => eikenhout-pallet
            [productcat] => Eikenhout
            [catalias] => eikenhout
            [quantity] => 1
            [kuubkosten] => 150|1 kuub
        )

)
```

But after adding the product again, the quantity is not increased. What am I doing wrong? I can see in my network tab that all data is correctly posted and there are no errors.

Comment: `+= $arr2['quantity']` should be `$arr2['quantity']+1;` maybe

Comment: @devpro But what if in the future I want customers to be able to add any quantity at once? For example add 10 products in one click?

Comment: @devpro `+=` is an acceptable operator in PHP..

Comment: If you are truely doing this `$_SESSION['producten'][$arr2['productid']] = $arr2;` then WHERE in the session array is `producten`

Comment: @RiggsFolly That is the name of my session. Printing `$_SESSION['producten']` shows me the second array in my question.

Comment: who will add quantity in future? end user? from where? any form or any product detail page? by using qty dropdown etc? if yes, then use `<input>` ... just suggestion

Comment: @devpro No I mean myself, the programmer and yes I will use an input not a dropdown for that.

Comment: then use this input value for qty update. like `$arr2['quantity']+$_POST['qty']` example

Comment: @devpro If I change `+=` to just `+` it still is not adding to the quantity.

Comment: its happening due to this check `if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {` its reset the session, once session reset, its goes to IF block not else to add qty

Comment: because `$_SESSION['cart']` is set then qty will work 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As devpro already said,
you are checking if the key 'cart' isset

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
```

But you are never setting that variable. Your code might just work when you change

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    // and turn session into array
    $_SESSION['producten'] = array();
}
```

to

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['producten'])) {
    // and turn session into array
    $_SESSION['producten'] = array();
}
```